# What is the difference between the .connect() function and the CONNECT method?

Tags: python, http, sockets

I am learning Python; specifically, I'm learning about network architecture and HTTP requests. The course example below demonstrates how to write a simple web browser.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')
mysock.close()
```

I understand that the `.connect()` function starts the two-way communication, effectively "opening the tunnel". The syntax is `socketname.connect(('address'),port)`

However, I am wondering if there is a difference between that function and the CONNECT method described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT). That syntax is:
CONNECT serverurl: port

Specifically, when is it appropriate to use one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The `.connect()` function is connecting the TCP socket to the remote server, which allows data to be sent to and received from the server. In your case you're using the TCP socket to send HTTP commands, and receive corresponding HTTP responses.

The HTTP `CONNECT` method is something completely different. It's a type of HTTP command, which include `GET` (the one you're using), `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc that can be sent over your connected socket. `CONNECT` is related to HTTP tunneling (i.e. having the web server proxy your requests to another server).

When you send a `CONNECT` command, you're basically instructing the server to forward future HTTP commands to a *different* HTTP server. So it is sort of like being 'connected' to that other server in a way.